# SELECT Brand and Model for cars which have been rented in December 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table called `Car` with columns `CarID, Brand, Model, ProdYear, Color`
and a table `Rent` with columns `RentID, CarID, RentDate, ReturnDate`.

How to SELECT Brand and Model for cars which have been rented in December 2000?

`RentDate` and `ReturnDate` are stored in `DATETIME` format (YYYY-MM-DD)

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simplistic scenario:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Brand, Model
FROM Car
WHERE (MONTH(RentDate) = 'December' AND YEAR(RentDate)) = 2000 or (MONTH(ReturnDate) = 'December'Year(ReturnDate) = 2000)
```

If you want to dig further and the following will cover four scenarios:

1. Rented earlier but returned in the year of Dec 2000
2. rented in 2000 and returned after Dec 2000
3. Rented in 2000 and returned also in Dec 2000

```
SELECT DISTINCT Brand, Model
FROM Car
WHERE RentDate  <='2020-12-31' AND ReturnDate >= '2020-12-01
```

Comment: Thanks! Create view, which allows to display the first and last names, where:
the result should contain data for both – i.e., Employees and Clients, and
data should be sorted by LastName column (in the descending order):

Comment: could you help me with this, please?

Answer (score 1):

Just learn simple join which might help you.

```
SELECT c.Brand,C.Model
FROM Car c 
INNER JOIN Rent r ON r.CarId = c.carId 
where Year(r.returnDate) = 2000
AND MONTH(r.returnDate) = 12
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you help me with this, please: Create view, which allows to display the first and last names, where:
the result should contain data for both – i.e., Employees and Clients, and
data should be sorted by LastName column (in the descending order):

Comment: I did like this: create view NameView as 
select FirstName, LastName                   from Client c, Employee e
where c.FirstName = e.FirstName
and c.LastName = e.LastName

Comment: But it gives me an error: 1) Ambiguous column name 'FirstName'.   2) Ambiguous column name 'LastName'.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you tips to create your request.

First of all, you have to make a **join** between your 2 table like shown :

```
... Car INNER JOIN Rent ON Car.CarID = Rent.CarID
```

Then you have to add a **where** clause :

```
Where RentDate in (SELECT RentID, RentDate From Rent WHERE MONTH = 12 AND YEAR = 2000)
```

As you see, you can use a double request to get all the RentID and Date.

I hope this will work for you and this help you.